# Optimize variables while iterating through rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have data like this:

```
x = 2

df =
Base | Base*x | Inc | Proj | After
  3  |    6   |  6  |   2  |   4
  3  |    6   |  10 |   1  |   9
  1  |    2   |  11 |   4  |   7
  2  |    4   |  11 |   0  |   11
```

'Base' is static

'Inc' = current row's 'Base' + previous row's 'After' value

'Proj' = static

'After' = Inc - Proj

I need to optimize x such that the average of all 'After' values is as close to 0 as possible.

If I use the excel solver add-in, it gives me an x value of 0.76. Is it possible to recreate something like this in Python? I need to scale this up to a much larger dataset than excel can handle.

Comment: Have a look at ```scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar```.

Comment: Your problem appears linear, so you should be able to solve it to a certain optimum  with `scipy.optimize.linprog`, all other methods implemented give you a local optimum, not necessarily the global.

Comment: Thanks Jay! Any tutorials you'd recommend?